# Got different output for same input in password encryption method in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have two methods `singup` and `signin` in Laravel. Use there `hash()` encryption method for password. But got two outputs for two methods (`signup` and `signin`).

Suppose I have input a password named 'abc' and from `signup` controller method I got the hash encrypted value

`$2y$10$fNfBqMh8vqdTkvLJcv0YI.9TLQr4/T4V38qRMgm6aWkanL8a1rCwW`

For the same input value I got different output from `signin` method

`$2y$10$u1fmJjQYKFmT79bB7nrD1.npDrn14YXkCQt.drxgoHURsOwrM319m`

Here is my `signup`form

```
public function signin(LoginFormValidation $request)
{
 $data = new User();
 $email = $request->email;
 $password = Hash::make($request->password);

 echo $password;
}
public function signup(RegistrationFormValidation $request)
{
 $data = new User();
 $email = $request->email;
 $password = Hash::make($request->password);

 echo $password;
}
```

`signup` from

```
<form class="cd-signin-modal__form" action="{{ url('/signup') }}" method="GET" id="registration-form">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
    <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--email cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signup-email" id="email">E-mail</label>
    <input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="reg_email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="reg_email">
    <div id="reg_email_error" class="val_error"></div>
</p>

<p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
    <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--password cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signup-password" id="password">Password</label>
    <input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="reg_password" type="text" placeholder="Password" name="reg_password">
    <div id="reg_password_error" class="val_error"></div>
</p>

<p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
    <input id="signup" class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding" type="submit" value="Create account">                                              
</p>
```

`signin` form

```
<form class="cd-signin-modal__form" action="{{ url('/signin') }}" method="GET" id="login-form">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
    <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--email cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
    <input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="login_email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">

    <div id="login_email_error" class="val_error"></div>
</p>

<p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
    <label class="cd-signin-modal__label cd-signin-modal__label--password cd-signin-modal__label--image-replace" for="signin-password">Password</label>
    <input class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width cd-signin-modal__input--has-padding cd-signin-modal__input--has-border" id="login_password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">

    <div id="login_password_error" class="val_error"></div>
</p>

<p class="cd-signin-modal__fieldset">
    <input id="signin" class="cd-signin-modal__input cd-signin-modal__input--full-width" type="submit" value="Login">
</p>
```

Comment: Laravel uses `bcrypt` hash algorithm to generate secure hashes. First `bcrypt` is not an encryption algorithm so don't be confused with the same output. Second `bcrypt` by design doesn't generate the same hash for each input string. so No need to be worry about it atlast It needs to be compared.

Comment: Just curious why this same code with this same params generates different values

Comment: Because if the output is not matched then how should I query in database using password to find out the user?

Comment: @bigwolk....yes...my ques is that point...why different !!

Comment: @bigwolk Because `bcrypt` always generates a random salt whether you specify or not. Raff you don't need to be worry about it just check through `Hash::check()` and you will be fine

Comment: A good idea is to read the aglorithm of `bcrypt`    `salt:     array of Bytes (16 bytes)           random salt` [bcrypt wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

Comment: @SaadSuri I think Yours answer is enough for that question.

Comment: @SaadSuri... user can't login with the same password what they used in signup..that's why I am worry.... what can i do now...

Comment: Because your code logic is absolute wrong. You're making hash on signin function(as supposed to check the credentials). At signin you should have used `Hash::check()`

Comment: @SaadSuri.. That means for same string the output will randomly change in `bcrypt`

Comment: Yes because of random salt

Comment: @SaadSuri...will you please give me the correct function code in the answer part ?

Answer (score 0):

Hash is not encryption. It's different.
Laravel uses brcypt to hash your password.
Each time you hash a password, it will generate different strings.

Now, if what you are trying to do is to check whether 2 passwords are the same or not, use Hash::check() method.